# amCharts + jQuery Mobile integration

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, amcharts

I am trying to include [AMCharts.js](http://www.amcharts.com/) in my jQuery Mobile application, but the chart is zoom-able or scroll-able. I can only use mouse wheel to zoom in-out, but when I tried to prepare [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/p0js34zr/1/), it works fine.

Only difference is that in my application, amchart is not on front page but comes after navigating 2 pages. I have included scripts in my .htm file.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="header" data-role="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <p> am charts <p>  
            <div id="chartdiv"></div>

      </div>
    <div id="footer" data-role="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

I get this error in my application: **Uncaught TypeError: a.touches.item is not a function** when I try to drag slider or zoom/scroll in graph.

Same error is coming for `[highstocks.js][3]` as well

Comment: Would you be able to create a fiddle that uses jQuery Mobile to display your setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the chart in the pageshow event of the page you navigate too:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page2", function () { ...
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/p0js34zr/2/)**

Comment: , I updated my code by creating chart on Pageshow , but still some problem is there , I am not able to scroll or zoom chart